# Serialize value-types without creating additional fields for 'value' in the database

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

With firestore it's possible to use `(data) class(es)`

```
data class Address(var person: Person = Person("", ""))
data class Person(var firstName: String = "", var lastName: String = "")
```

that will be serialized into their properties like that

```
document:
  person:
     firstName: "John"
     lastName: "Doe"
```

However, I'd like to have a value-type for `firstName` like this one:

```
data class FirstName(var value: String = "") {
    init {
        // check value etc.
    }
}
```

but when I use it for the `firstName` in its *default* form, it'll serialize into

```
document:
  person:
     firstName:
        value: "John"
     lastName: "Doe"
```

In order to de/serialize it, I use the standard mechanism like:

```
// Serialize/write
firestore
   .collection("path")
   .document()
   .set(address)

// Deserialize/read e.g.
firestore
   .collection("path")
   .whereEqualTo("person.firstName", "John")
   .get()
   .await()
   .toObjects(Address::class.java)
```

How can I make it serialize into and deserialize from a string so that the `value` field is not created?

Comment: Would you mind posting the code you use to serialize the the class?

Comment: @Greg there's nothing more into it. I just call `firestore.collection("path").document().set(address)`. That's all and deserialize it with `toObject(Address::class.java)`. Just the standard mechanism.

Comment: Not sure I can help with this one, ultimately the class seems to get serialized by this (or a very similar class):
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/843b963679a3a02f044f9f8bdabadfbcfbbe1202/firebase-firestore/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/firestore/util/CustomClassMapper.java

Personally I think it would be more conventional and end up with simpler code if you just made the classes match the expected database schema (and convert them to DTO classes if you need a different structure somewhere else).

Comment: @Greg nice! I didn't realize there was source-code for it. I've checked it and all the calls to `isAnnotationPresent` but it doesn't look like there is one allowing us to specify a custom mapper.

Comment: It just seems to be using the getters from your POJO unfortunately, it's implied from the comments that `CustomClassMapper` can be used to control serialisation but there doesn't appear to be any solid examples of this. You could just manually convert it to a Map before passing to `document().set()` I guess!

Comment: seems @Greg suggestion is the right thing to do. can you add it as an answer ? and I think opening a github issue would really worth it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately it seems that the classes are serialised [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/843b963679a3a02f044f9f8bdabadfbcfbbe1202/firebase-firestore/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/firestore/util/CustomClassMapper.java), doesn't look like you're able to customise it.

Personally I think it would be more conventional and end up with simpler code if you just made the classes match the expected database schema (and convert them to DTO classes if you need a different structure somewhere else).